# Matlab: image plot caption overlapping the image

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm plotting several image subplots into one Matlab figure. (using *imshow()* and *subplot()*, respectively *[subaxis()](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3696)*)

Using title() to describe the images consumes too much space in the figure.

Therefore, I would like to write a caption overlapping part of the image (something like *legend()* for function plots), but I can't find a corresponding function for that.

Is there some common way how to do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If it is just a text label, you could use the function `text`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return a handle for the title and modify it:

```
figure(1)

handle=title('My Title');
set(handle,'Position',[0.5 0.9]);
```

Comment: Thanks, thats what I was looking for. Adding additional params makes it look how I wanted.

`set(handle,'Position',[size(image,2)/2 50],'BackgroundColor',[1 1 1],'EdgeColor',[0 0 0]);`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the text command to place text anywhere on the image, including OUTSIDE the axes.

```
plot([1 2 3 4])
xlim([1 4])
ylim([1 4])
text(mean(xlim), max(ylim)+0.05*diff(ylim), 'The title', 'horizontalAlignment', 'center')
```

You can edit other text properties as you would any other Matlab text object.

Comment: I'll also add that sometimes the subplot commands leave too much white space between axes. If this is something you run into often, it may be worth learning how to manually position axes within the figure. For example, most of my pipeline for creating figures for academic papers is done in Matlab, and I control the exact placement of each axes, titles, etc.